# Is there a general term for divisibility for each whole number?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a general term for divisibility? I.e. A number which is divisible by 5 is called ____. A number which is divisible by 7 is called ____.

> 15 is divisible by 5. As such it is called ____ or called a ____ number.

there should be a word - maybe one starting with pent ...

Comment: Composite number: https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/composite-number.html

Comment: 15 is a **multiple** of 5.

Comment: Are you asking because of even and odd numbers?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a term for numbers divisible specifically by 5, a different term for numbers divisible specifically by 7, etc.?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - The major edit was not done by Robert, but either way the question still reads the way I interpreted its original wording (as per my previous comment), it's just a bit clearer. (Although it could be made clearer still.)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - You don't have to rely on memory, you can see the full edit history. The original tried to distinguish between numbers divisible by 5 and numbers divisible 7, but it was worded pretty vaguely.

Comment: Ah... Thank you. @nnnnnn Got it.

Comment: And a word for one divisible by 173? It would become ridiculous. Other than 'multiples of n', the productive way of handling this is 'residue class zero modulo n'.

Answer (score 1):

[Composite number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/composite-number.html):

> A whole number that can be made by multiplying other whole numbers.
>
> Example: 6 can be made by 2 × 3 so is a composite number.
>
> But 7 can not be made by multiplying other whole numbers (1×7 would
>   work, but we said to use other whole numbers) so is not a composite
>   number, it is a prime number.
>
> All whole numbers above 1 are either composite or prime.